# Test a function with 3 if by unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, passwords, pycharm

I build a simple function that control if a password have:

I built a simple function that checks if a password contains:

1. at least one uppercase letter,
2. a number,
3. must be at least 8 characters long

The function is:

```
import re

class Password():
    def validate(password):
        while True:
            if len(password) < 8:
                print("False")
            elif re.search('[0-9]', password) is None:
                print("False")
            elif re.search('[A-Z]', password) is None:
                print("False")
            else:
                print("Your password seems fine")
                break
```

This function is saved in a file called password.py

Now I want do a unit test that control each condition:

```
import Password
import unittest

class TestPassword(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_password(self):
        valid = Password.Password()
        self.assertEqual("asdfA1qw",valid.validate())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But I don't know how. How can i set a control for each if?

Comment: Why don't you make the function return True if the pwd is ok?

Comment: There appears to be no reason for `validate` to be a method of a class rather than a simple function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `validate` can just be a bare function that returns `True` or `False` as appropriate.

```
def validate(password):
    if len(password) < 8:
        return False
    elif re.search('[0-9]', password) is None:
        return False
    elif re.search('[A-Z]', password) is None:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Now the tests are trivial:

```
import Password
import unittest

class TestPassword(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_password(self):
        self.assertTrue(Password.validate("asdfA1qw"))

    def test_short_password(self):
        self.assertFalse(Password.validate("foo"))
```

You would define separate tests with various invalid passwords to trigger each of your conditions. (One with a too-short password, another without any numbers, etc.)

The task of actually inputting a password until it validates does not belong *in* `validate`; it should be a separate loop that *uses* `validate`:

```
while True:
    password = input("Enter a password: ")
    if Password.validate(password):
        break
    print("Password invalid, try again", file=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly set control on each `if` statement. You have to provide right value to `valid.validate()` in your test function to force it to go into right `if`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your function properly, you could make it return an individual value for each case:

```
def validate(password):
    if len(password) < 8:
        return 'password must have at least 8 characters'
    elif re.search('[0-9]', password) is None:
        return 'password must at least contain a numeric character'
    elif re.search('[A-Z]', password) is None:
        return 'password must aat least contain an upper case character'
    else:
        return "Your password seems fine"
```

Then you can check those branches by coming up with a password that will break one of these rules. e.g.: `abcdefg`, `abcdefgh`, `4bcdefgh`, `4Bcdefgh`

Then have another method use that function an make it have a reasonable return value, too.

(Opinionated note: If you write your test first, you don't run into such problems, since you will already design your code in a way that it is easy testable)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is very weird, I suppose that you prefer Java programming language:

1. In Python you not need a class for writing a function.
2. Your function *need not* print something, it is a matter of a caller. It is sufficient that it returns something (`True` or `False` in your case).
3. Direct comparing with `None` is not a Pythonic way.
4. `while True:` and `break` is meaningless in this situation.
5. `elif` are useless if you will use `return`.

So it's sufficient to rewrite is as

```
import re

def validate(password):
    if len(password) < 8:
        return False
    if not re.search('[0-9]', password):
        return False
    if not re.search('[A-Z]', password):
        return False
    return True
```

Now, because your UnitTest is probably in an another module than your tested code (because PyCharm creates it for you in that way), you first have to `import password` - as your tested function is in the `password.py` file.

In UnitTest you *must* define a test class (as you did), and test methods (as you did). You may define as many tests in a single test method as you wish, but much better is to define different test method for every test.

Tests themselves (in your testing methods) will be now - after refactoring your original code - very simple: We will test only for return values `True` or `False`. An example:

```
self.assertTrue(password.validate("asdfA1qw"))
```